# Overwrite WP srcset code - so we can use ImgIX

Tags: wordpress, srcset, imgix

We are looking to add ImgIX to a WP site, we have the upload working, via an S3 bucket, but we can't insert the new srcset code in to the img attribute.

There is a WP plugin that we have been using but it doesn't show how to overwrite WPs native srcset.

Does anyone have experience with this?

WP doesn't allow you to overwrite their native srcset code, that we can see. But there must be a way as the WP plugin exists.

We used the PHP library to generate the srcset.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple filters that you'll want to check:

- [`wp_get_attachment_image_attributes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_get_attachment_image_attributes/)
- [`wp_get_attachment_image`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_get_attachment_image/)

These are both used by [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/). Test if changes to those filters makes changes, and if not, then there's some other function being used to insert the markup.